# Powershell Workflow runbook - authentication failed

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have an [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/) `Run As account`. When I run the following code ([from step 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual#step-5---add-authentication-to-manage-azure-resources) of Azure online tutorial) on the runbook in Azure Portal, I get the error shown below. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how can we resolve the issue?

**runbook code**:

```
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID `
-ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$AzureContext = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID
```

**Error**:

```
Failed At line:4 char:1
+ Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Cannot find the 'Disable-AzContextAutosave' command. If this command is defined as a workflow, ensure it is defined before the workflow that calls it. If it is a command intended to run directly within Windows PowerShell (or is not available on this system), place it in an InlineScript: 'InlineScript { Disable-AzContextAutosave }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you havn't imported the `Az.Accounts` module into your automation account. `Disable-AzContextAutosave`, `Connect-AzAccount` and `Select-AzSubscription` are from this module.

Follow this guide to [Import Az modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-az-modules).

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, the runbook for authentication worked. Now I have another issue in the next step. In case you get a chance, I've posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64950705/1232087).