# Cannot find the 'Start-AzVM' command when used in a runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am working on this [official tutorial from MS Azure team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual#step-6---add-code-to-start-a-virtual-machine) to run a `PowerShell Workflow runbook` to start a `VM`. But when I start the following runbook (from step 6 of the tutorial), I get the error shown below. **Question**: What I may be missing, and how can we resolve the issue?

**rinbook code**:

```
workflow MyFirstRunbook-Workflow
{
# Ensures that you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$AzureContext = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

Start-AzVM -Name 'vm-cs-web01' -ResourceGroupName 'rg-cs-ansible1' -AzContext $AzureContext
}
```

**Error**:

```
Failed At line:11 char:1
+ Start-AzVM -Name 'vm-cs-web01' -ResourceGroupName 'rg-cs-ansible1' -A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Cannot find the 'Start-AzVM' command. If this command is defined as a workflow, ensure it is defined before the workflow that calls it. If it is a command intended to run directly within Windows PowerShell (or is not available on this system), place it in an InlineScript: 'InlineScript { Start-AzVM }'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Start-AzVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/start-azvm?view=azps-5.1.0) is from the [`Az.Compute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/?view=azps-5.1.0) module, so you need to import this module into your Automation Account.

To import this module, go to **Automation Account -> Modules -> Browse Gallery -> Search Az.Compute -> Import**

If you want to have all `Az.*` modules imported, then you can just import the [`Az`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/5.1.0) module from the gallery. To import this for your automation account, go to **Automation Account -> Modules -> Browse Gallery -> Search Az -> Import**.

Comment: The above issue got resolved and displayed `completed`. But in the same run [another error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64957072/1232087) occurred in the same `runbook`. I'm not sure if the doc is outdated and using old syntax or I'm missing something.