# Start-AzVM : Cannot bind parameter 'DefaultProfile' when running an Azure runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am working on this [official tutorial from MS Azure team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual) to run a `PowerShell Workflow runbook` to start a `VM`. But when I start the following runbook ([from step 6 of the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual#step-6---add-code-to-start-a-virtual-machine)), I get the error shown below. **Question**: What I may be missing, and how can we resolve the issue?

**Remark**: [Start-AzVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/start-azvm?view=azps-5.1.0) is from [Az.Compute module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/?view=azps-5.1.0) that I have already imported.

**runbook code**:

```
workflow MyFirstRunbook-Workflow
{
# Ensures that you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$AzureContext = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

Start-AzVM -Name 'vm-cs-web01' -ResourceGroupName 'rg-cs-ansible1' -AzContext $AzureContext
}
```

**Error**:

```
Start-AzVM : Cannot bind parameter 'DefaultProfile'. Cannot convert the "a76c7e8f-210d-45e5-8f5e-525015b1c881" value of 
type "Deserialized.Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureSubscription" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.Core.IAzureContextContainer".
At MyFirstRunbook-Workflow:11 char:11
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-AzVM], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StartAzureVMCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is a mistake in the doc, in this scenario, it should use `Set-AzContext` to set the subscription instead of using `Get-AzSubscription` to get the subscription, change the command like below, it will work fine.

```
workflow MyFirstRunbook-Workflow
{
# Ensures that you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

Start-AzVM -Name 'vm-cs-web01' -ResourceGroupName 'rg-cs-ansible1' -AzContext $AzureContext
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you for pointing out the error in the document (despite the fact that I had mistakenly provided an incorrect link to the tutorial  - but you found out the correct link. I have corrected, the link, as well). Also thank you for taking your time to first test the runbook yourself and posting an screenshot of the output so other readers could see the output, as well.